# PostgreSQL Check or trigger

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called products and one of columns is called names.

When I insert a new product, I want to check if name of the new product already exists in names and then show an error message.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is the data type of `names`?

Answer (score 1):

You should add a unique constraint on your names column:

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD UNIQUE (names);
```